# Invalid type when assigning values to wrapper

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, wrapper-class

I have a nested wrapper class but I am failing to understand how to assign values to the variables of the nested class.

```
public class Req_Wrapper {
    public Envelope Envelope {get;set;}

    public class Envelope {
        public Header Header {get;set;}
        public Body Body {get;set;}
    }

    public class Header {
        public RequestContext RequestContext {get;set;}
    }

    public class RequestContext {
        public String UserID {get;set;}
        public String RequestMessageId {get;set;}
        public DateTime RequestTimestamp {get;set;}
    }
}
```

First, I tried to assign the values as we do with static variables.

```
Req_Wrapper rq = new Req_Wrapper();
rq.Envelope.Header.RequestContext.UserID = '123';
```

But this approach gave me attempt to de reference.... error

So I tried to take the full OOP way:

```
Req_Wrapper rq = new Req_Wrapper();
rq.Envelope env = new rq.Envelope();
env.Header head = new env.Header(); // this lines throws invalid type
rq.Envelope.Header head2 = new rq.Envelope.Header(); // this one also throws invalid type
rq.Envelope.Header.RequestContext.UserID = '123';
```

How to assign a variable to this wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're not working inside of the `Req_Wrapper` class, you need to use the outer class name as well when you reference inner classes.

e.g. `Req_Wrapper.Envelope` and `Req_Wrapper.Header`

So the code you're looking for here is

```java
// Get a wrapper instance first
Req_Wrapper rq = new Req_Wrapper();

// set the "envelope" variable of the request using <outer>.<inner>
rq.envelope = new Reeq_Wrapper.Envelope();

// set the "header" and "body" variables of the envelope
rq.evelope.header = new Req_Wrapper.Header();
rq.envelope.body = new Req_Wrapper.Body();

// set the request context for the header
rq.envelope.header.requestContext = new Req_Wrapper.RequestContext();

// and finally, use dot notation to dig into your wrapper instance to set a variable
rq.envelope.header.requestContext.UserID = '123';
```

You could also, alternatively, create variables to hold each inner class instance, and then get all of the "child" objects assigned later

```java
// Make all of the object instances you'll need
Req_Wrapper rq = new Req_Wrapper();
Req_Wrapper.Envelope myEnvelope = new Req_Wrapper.Envelope();
Req_Wrapper.Header myHeader = new Req_Wrapper.Header();
Req_Wrapper.Body myBody = new Req_Wrapper.Body();
Req_Wrapper.RequestContext context = new Req_Wrapper.RequestContext();

// Set fields
context.UserID = '123';

// Tie everything together
rq.envelope = myEnvelope;
myEnvelope.header = myHeader;
myEnvelope.body = myBody;
myHeader.requestContext = context;
```

It's not a great idea to name a variable the same as the class (e.g. `public Envelope Envelope`), and general code style says that variables should start with a lowercase letter. I believe that it *can* work, but shadowing the class name is going to make debugging harder. It should be fine as long as you don't have any real code inside your wrapper class(es), but it'll possibly be an issue the minute you try to do so much as add a constructor in your wrapper class(es).

Answer (score 0):

It takes a bit more time to set up but works well in the long run

```
public class Req_Wrapper {
  public Envelope envelope {get;set;}
  public Req_Wrapper withEnvelope(Envelope val) {this.envelope = val; return this;} 

  public class Envelope {
      public Header header {get;set;}
      public Body body {get;set;}
      public Envelope withHeader(Header val) {this.header = val; return this;}
      public Body withBody(Body val) {this.body = val; return this;}
  }

  public class Header {
      public RequestContext requestContext {get;set;}
      public Header withRequestContext(RequestContext val) this.requestContext = val; return this;}
  }

  public class RequestContext {
    public String userID {get;set;}
    public String requestMessageId {get;set;}
    public DateTime requestTimestamp {get;set;}
    public RequestContext withUserId(String val) {this.userId = val; return this;}
    public RequestContext withRequestMessageId(String val) {this.requestMessageId = val; return this;}
    public RequestContext withRequestTimestamp(Datetime val) {this.requestTimestamp = val; return this;} 
  }
  
}
```

Then you can use (including in testmethods)

```
Req_Wrapper reqWrapper = new Req_Wrapper()
 .withEnvelope(new Envelope()
   .withHeader(new Header()
     .withRequestContext(new RequestContext()
        .withUserId('abc')
        .withRequestMessageId('msgId')
        .withRequestTimestamp(someDatetime)
     )
   )
 );
```